# Azure Service App Becomes Unavailable After Deploying ASP.Net Web Core App

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I've deployed an ASP.NET core web app targeting .NET 7.0. The app works fine in Visual Studio. However, when deployed to Azure App Service I get a simple "The service is unavailable" message displayed after I launch the app and click around for a bit. It occurs randomly...there is no pattern that causes this. I restart the app service and the app will work for a click or two and then this message appears again and the app is down. There are no failures when I check Application Insights. I've tried to scale/up/down/out with no change in behavior. I use no application gateway or front door at the moment.

**App Service Settings**

[image]

[image]

```
Connecting...
2023-01-27T20:24:07  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service. The default timeout is 2 hours. Change the timeout with the App Setting SCM_LOGSTREAM_TIMEOUT (in seconds).
2023-01-27 20:23:55 ~1DATAMAGNIFIERADMIN GET /api/logstream/ X-ARR-LOG-ID=cf48d177-921a-4dc5-9446-9b629859c8a3 443 - 73.84.82.7 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/109.0.0.0+Safari/537.36+Edg/109.0.1518.55 - - datamagnifieradmin.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 64 1126 1495 66236
2023-01-27 20:24:55 ~1DATAMAGNIFIERADMIN GET /api/logstream/http X-ARR-LOG-ID=b8b63d16-153b-4d16-a000-ad454543b9fb 443 - 73.84.82.7 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/109.0.0.0+Safari/537.36+Edg/109.0.1518.55 - - datamagnifieradmin.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 64 5659 1507 71199
2023-01-27 20:25:44 DATAMAGNIFIERADMIN GET /AdUsers X-ARR-LOG-ID=7579c45a-1658-493f-8a77-c8adabb8378d 443 - 73.84.82.7 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/109.0.0.0+Safari/537.36+Edg/109.0.1518.55 ARRAffinity=92ca53ad8db4fbb93d4d3b7d8ab54dcf8ffecb2d731f25b0e91ad575d7534c3f;+ARRAffinitySameSite=92ca53ad8db4fbb93d4d3b7d8ab54dcf8ffecb2d731f25b0e91ad575d7534c3f;+ARRAffinity=fd3e4b2d012080ee1ba6f00bb456f71017e9bb5bc3d7d8b6d99a3e13ad27cbf0;+ARRAffinitySameSite=fd3e4b2d012080ee1ba6f00bb456f71017e9bb5bc3d7d8b6d99a3e13ad27cbf0;+.AspNetCore.Session=CfDJ8K%2BoVdxUgaZHkxTXB5kqCDNFs2m9QjxHt1tYfSELbYcsWLq8nj7Eo5jQXYS7eENpIxdt3nHQVe0LoiKArNJ5CnjaQ41l4p9XSqRN0cqe%2Fvs94Drsjw5DeUlHSyLG1eRkG2%2Fiu74ox1VqbzsvmO0GNcQH4u1i1e9xvW%2FZcxJEfzQL;+ai_user=EUSRJlOpuAOSDnWBOJ11nl|2023-01-26T18:52:35.633Z;+.AspNetCore.Cookies=CfDJ8K-oVdxUgaZHkxTXB5kqCDPwHEIChhppdJqUAniIH-zNeCI_31qKsDyys_qu4PJ1a11bQi3EMIuZ9ysNch9tPboNBxNPKY_fB4raf2PLTZAk4OKw5BzfkYkAEcOkX4FPojNDrsTfza_Se2oFIvKoa1_mNF_tWCIhGdnQTltZOaqijKxw-aJujl5vPa2-vVNscioSHSrbuYzqEpTT3lzyahrB4ZgN9JTgoz-upzD23H7T7Apg9ILYAB49C64LD1HCJWYeWIjV-0qYkf8uXgUt8TfVB79kwNPQs17E6oTLzeo9kMwzhNa9ACl9S5r69lZT2lzFkMOL85P_CbNMeHvQ3C6RCYfBzpSVDnla4SfEnxDqP0sEWZXUL0DJSAIoa9j1Olu6nusUQbrWXMPmoMDzU7dmXlghyO126ze-KOp92JPqEa_nvlLvO018iNRBms1trqaape5cd6Lpeaxv8zeD5hCyAqd7tpY1P3SNdGjpdyBb7LCCH4vkC0i5QKs-tQxc0YUnY6bs2b475Vl5lZcKHXdFUqVuQAqs0udu9nyWCyBmUDG-1C4hU3SPhAyVUcfrqu1UucuTTYzSkHI01_hwBVtI8rmS5pvFQXr2Qa9ARQkoObkyzxCQ5ebLWl63L1ZY2zauRCQDdp0D7tDImvPxnC8BfnqiOJjC5FNWDhUdli_jT-1qVJfcZ2rTj12037DyC5RY9oye7PNtW1VU8EndbxIbjV21D2XypDYUAWO6ynv9kB6EI7Qqy6oqNLS93dt0hp_lzBW1es6tIssNwV27u7Tl1vHh33tWzEQmMmIwl3DQ2tEGsQMKEI7MuwOE5U77uJweda3dIcq0C-4CbBa2Q1fHms3nX2txzuee3L2ARWjUcsuy5u7lnokAzNNBIbvoOCTkD1DJk_ZTkbyEk8PENZ7q04pknr6qlwgMVJXtz9-qlFxbpnJyXnAzy2Z5C3EeWDUjroYmhjjJ1Y-E7fWZ4dX4sZRFEodO8YCv7-9ztEITxCScTRccWd3XzXv69P11BSajtorrRgJHRfPukg5lLMJF15jmJyQFuQEYBKvVXQBr_25Lyl2WPdBzsj1ThCYtO1Ux-QLtstOrj5beWD-mEpnMsmVG1Ad5w0odhEYWYTZgZ2kw-W4Gtpr_745oDpvuE3ug2zuR1yRtpazQdwKA716q9Hq8leDRmfrmPjtgLeg8qtTMLRp2a63ES5oqX1XGP66164VcurQODjhtXDIcqJQq83xMmL-64pu584FRNRn2oNXSphmvh-qrxxH_1YVnjBFFlteo0qhvEF98pjG0mn5JqgtQiqLwdAbEghon0WWMPYTuFu7bCBSvR8P3w0Ahn47udrkijxySsD013O0ugO-gP3BcqCvTKC6OrxPjuou6Zv4BhnXU8666n57RCDJbf-ul64dGlejPhap6IfGTj9NCOChwZL2RdqjtGC8q96m2sCIvB60J6CSao1HhAknIMYCimmgEA0cuSprg6rH7MCvkcKIGleri3caBLnEYiWXvykEvsQgVWhKSH0R7lwU5CjC05NOWVZAjI8CMn8sU4UOm_CoYsB59jgc9J2bce2iBtaI84RzNbw58okQhUdYVpn1yUgQBtvLzhnHz7yCCAqhTbzlnfbmcLB56XCgqdMC1rmgFOyAi-oa9QWCMzmEheHTFoyrlDg5yzKGEv675p1JL0owQOtPdILYnY65InsufpSKd7yFbY6hTJpc0WLDiSotZhIlGNE8n5pex28g7oILpt8G0LMpb96VH-8ZYLaIaunBeB7fhCrL3ZczOcAW_vhGW3kd3eCVeF9XDTNjayhIJxlcIbYvCb1HwSzEEI3qh8V3NyKAEg-aOTN-oiMMZjQlpZ2EbfGVL44VtCubJI2zKYEBAm90ppcF4CtmdznUI98Sp4WyDRzHrlkMMRqZ8gBOJ6AHajv1JZh-bQ7Vv48_AfGc7rX4FSml4fWhaqIFij3jBZkK_eWdZSSNGoKVlMmUyD_-D9Yi9lC5hZ0kFWjGTR5l1LCIzI8ZyXcQR-DddhjcxQKPzIB1W1EYKDIaoS4bZoMsEvZeL0_vKQywCzvy88v_rydWi7Vgyw6mYbeiGTX3QbsVkAbTACsP6QfyP4_Bx2pVs9p4peQlmJr_L_vHhVHPp1itz-B1aJmZO_JK1FRV41qqPXg1QDW6kxelwxmpPtar1JnpHCDUPiaHD3wAOhdRL7JSKHzsoZrB5Aiv6ii70qOJwkYZHxxStLYewp90Xrur9bh7OMv59k4gUSsd-Ru9dBK9ChjBJYNkYOfMHCi0XZaJ_7xYg79E0UbIxAOuirL33HYLg7ojemp3_0e9aBhuuHIi8tEpIyVlqv8blWsGdMdH7WpO4qiSGYjjFpOQT3Q61BWIGXAf5ME0jEE3sLgZWc3s7KGMjJiL4f0LAsjoVNlTJTYqsj7eXrb3bXCOiWcAHrTIP8DQCHxdqghuKwrsBcZsl_caoFtD3Y4n2081CJwWG8zQ2gdA7XXUjUwdabHgf2Exf0u0vQ9nC9tFb-Tyd5hHe98sNkPGHA4sMZNMw6_pXa0EowyE25M_pzP1_w65PsEMXChuAoHhuzx-A9-PibgEdRei7wz1LEMxlmW3PGKSictUo8ulKc-gUsWZ02xbHgdO16ArFZ0qzMFlG4Uq89RafsGEcaaH2zIjz-Dk5wu0ssv0nLu0urHD_6_eFpA3ZoT6lZFefIXYEslozScRsdJn4Y3dgk0PPktTAHC-fiTVCVOQVgIaZwP2YUZrTrauibTcwFhOH8zqwMPW70hTf3NfQ1RKMhUCKUpiq5xFOj7wl-dBstvP5r0CfQktzQUo0S8vHzOnm87-NG6ZFAmZQFH2HW7TuIZQsug8lwtagAE28V_iwW01by34nN4f0AfdOh4pL_FDRkjHw80AmoYgR-s8pIoDlQWqFsfOeOsyX-e0TqCeLneSigjEZ8mvzyCYyegll0vwAGAeNUkgidMss4hQB7pjF8nGdFdVg_7mO-70XfnNeAeFZcFp9etsbvUWpKtWH50EtVBP68dI;+.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.cdV5uW_Ejgc=CfDJ8K-oVdxUgaZHkxTXB5kqCDPyuX47rnbJlggAPR8af6SEqDkVGkT30QvUXdrJ7GyJxffRsElqUZS41a3-955Z01xrG28cdYLcVFCROPjdqBeanz18i3WWyoO3j2aRo3kgrlH8O3OHrGqsW9kZ2vuAqZ8 https://www.datamagnifierportal.com/ www.datamagnifierportal.com 200 0 0 5077 5267 5099
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>IIS Detailed Error - 503.0 - Server has been shutdown</title><style type="text/css"><!--body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;}code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;}.config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;}pre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;}ul,ol{margin:10px 0 10px 5px;}ul.first,ol.first{margin-top:5px;}fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;word-break:break-all;}.summary-container fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-top:4px;}legend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;}legend{color:#333333;;margin:4px 0 8px -12px;_margin-top:0px;font-weight:bold;font-size:1em;}a:link,a:visited{color:#007EFF;font-weight:bold;}a:hover{text-decoration:none;}h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;}h3{font-size:1.4em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#CC0000;}h4{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 5px 0;}#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS",Verdana,sans-serif;color:#FFF;background-color:#5C87B2;}#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}.summary-container,.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}.content-container p{margin:0 0 10px 0;}#details-left{width:35%;float:left;margin-right:2%;}#details-right{width:63%;float:left;overflow:hidden;}#server_version{width:96%;_height:1px;min-height:1px;margin:0 0 5px 0;padding:11px 2% 8px 2%;color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#5A7FA5;border-bottom:1px solid #C1CFDD;border-top:1px solid #4A6C8E;font-weight:normal;font-size:1em;color:#FFF;text-align:right;}#server_version p{margin:5px 0;}table{margin:4px 0 4px 0;width:100%;border:none;}td,th{vertical-align:top;padding:3px 0;text-align:left;font-weight:normal;border:none;}th{width:30%;text-align:right;padding-right:2%;font-weight:bold;}thead th{background-color:#ebebeb;width:25%;}#details-right th{width:20%;}table tr.alt td,table tr.alt th{}.highlight-code{color:#CC0000;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;}.clear{clear:both;}.preferred{padding:0 5px 2px 5px;font-weight:normal;background:#006633;color:#FFF;font-size:.8em;}--></style>
</head><body><div id="content"><div class="content-container"><h3>HTTP Error 503.0 - Server has been shutdown</h3><h4>The service is unavailable.</h4></div><div class="content-container"><fieldset><h4>Most likely causes:</h4><ul>   <li>An invalid identity in the application pool could cause this error.</li>    <li>The application pool is no longer running because of configuration or reaching application failure limits.</li>     <li>The concurrent application request limit was reached.</li> </ul></fieldset></div><div class="content-container"><fieldset><h4>Things you can try:</h4><ul>  <li>Check the event logs and the HTTP error logs for more information.</li> </ul></fieldset></div>
<div class="content-container"><fieldset><h4>Detailed Error Information:</h4><div id="details-left"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr class="alt"><th>Module</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;AspNetCoreModuleV2</td></tr><tr><th>Notification</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ExecuteRequestHandler</td></tr><tr class="alt"><th>Handler</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;aspNetCore</td></tr><tr><th>Error Code</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0x8007045b</td></tr>
</table></div><div id="details-right"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr class="alt"><th>Requested URL</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;https://DataMagnifierAdmin:80/Customers</td></tr><tr><th>Physical Path</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;C:\home\site\wwwroot\Customers</td></tr><tr class="alt"><th>Logon Method</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr><tr><th>Logon User</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr>
</table><div class="clear"></div></div></fieldset></div>
<div class="content-container"><fieldset><h4>More Information:</h4>This error occurs when the worker process was unable to start. This could be due to an invalid identity or configuration, or because the concurrent request limit was reached.<p><a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&amp;IIS70Error=503,0,0x8007045b,14393">View more information &raquo;</a></p><p>Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:</p>
</fieldset></div></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Is it connect to database or third party services

Comment: Chances are there's an issue in your application somewhere that's causing this behavior. Enable (some) logging in App Service Log under the Monitoring category, and check the Log stream as you use the application.

Comment: @MaythamFahmi Yes, I connect to an Azure SQL DB in my tenant.

Comment: In many cases a connection can cause the issue if it is not set correctly up. application insight should configure correct up in your project before you can see error messages

Comment: Can you share out App Stream logs?

Comment: Have you configured any limitations on Kestrel max request? And how are you publishing your application?

Comment: @MuhammadHannan I'm deploying via Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition. Deployment mode is Framework-dependent, Target Runtime is Portable. I've not configured any limitations on Kestrel.

Comment: Okay, try opening an Azure support ticket. As to diagnosing the issue need something to repro the issue but I think that won't be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every call to WebApplication.CreateBuilder() creates a new IISNativeApplication instance.  Calling multiple times results in eventual disposal, which leads to return of the 503 response as described.

Only one of the following should be called and only one time at the initialization of the application:

> ```
> ConfigureWebHostDefaults
> WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder
> WebApplication.CreateBuilder
> Explicit calls to UseIIS
> ```

To resolve, search your code for any calls to the above and remove all except the one that is usually at the very beginning of Program.cs.

This post describes this problem in detail:
[ASP.NET Core: 503 Server has been shutdown](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/asp-net-core-503-server-has-been-shutdown/ba-p/3830338)

Answer (score 0):

- I tried to reproduce the steps that are given in my local system and followed the below steps.
- I have created a ASP.NET core web in Visual studio and added a sample Azure SQL DB with the connect services s below.

[image]

- After connecting the Azure SQL DB deploy the ASP.NET core to app service as below.

[image]

- After deploying the ASP.NET Core to app service I have changed some setting as below.
- Navigate to configuration and added settings as you followed.
  [image]
- Goto log stream and change the setting as below.

[image]

- When I Click on app service URL it will look like below.

[image]

> HTTP Error 503.0 - Server has been shutdown

- According to my research **An** HTTP 503.0 **error** indicates that the server is currently **unavailable.
- This can** be due to **various reasons such as** maintenance or server shutdown. In App Service, **this** could mean that the app is **unavailable** for maintenance or due to **issues** with the server hosting the app.
- To resolve this issue, you should try **to access** the app later or contact the **App Service** support team to determine the cause and **see** if there is an estimated time **to** resolution.

Comment: I do not find this helpful.